# Create a InputStream that receives data through a socket in Swift 3 (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

So my issue is getting a InputStream to work within swift for the iOS platform. I wrote some code and will post it below, but basically I have an Android client that sends data to the IP of the iOS client. Unfortunately the Android client says the connection was refused to connect to iOS client. I'm really not too sure what I'm doing wrong here as I think the code looks solid, so I'm kind of confused. By the way this my first time working with sockets in swift(iOS) so please understand I'm new to this and am here to learn through example code.

**ViewControler.swift**

```
var inputstream: InputStream?
var outputstream: OutputStream?
var host: CFString?
var port: UInt32?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initNetworkCommunication()
}
func initNetworkCommunication(){
    host = "192.168.1.187" as CFString
    port = 55555
    var readstream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writestream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host!, port!, &readstream, &writestream)

    inputstream? = readstream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputstream? = writestream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputstream?.delegate = self as! StreamDelegate
    outputstream?.delegate = self as! StreamDelegate


    inputstream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    outputstream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

    inputstream?.open()
    Status.text = "Input Stream Opened"
    outputstream?.open()
    Status.text = "Output Stream Opened"

}
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handleEvent eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    switch (eventCode){
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("Can not connect to the host!")
        Status.text = "Cannot connect to: \(host ?? "Null Host" as CFString)"
        break
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        outputstream?.close()
        outputstream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        outputstream = nil
        break
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        Status.text = "Recieving data..."
        NSLog("HasBytesAvaible")
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4096)
        if ( aStream == inputstream){
            while (inputstream?.hasBytesAvailable)!{
                var len = inputstream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                if(len! > 0){
                    Status.text = "Collected data..."
                    var data1 = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: buffer.count)
                    Status.text = "Converted Data to NSData..."
                    var str64 = data1.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength64Characters)
                    Status.text = "Decode Base64..."
                    let data: NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: str64 , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
                    // turn  Decoded String into Data
                    Status.text = "Turning Base64 data into image..."
                    let dataImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                    Status.text = "Done"
                    // pass the data image to image View.:)
                    Display.image = dataImage
                    Status.text = "Image Displayed"
                }
            }
        }
        break
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        NSLog("OpenCompleted")
        break
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        NSLog("HasSpaceAvailable")
        break
    default:
        print("Unknown event")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Android device is trying to connect to the iOS device, and from the code you've posted, the iOS device is trying to connect to the Android device. That's not how socket networking works.

One of the devices (or both, if this a peer to peer setup) needs to listen for connections on a particular port. See this guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW8) for information about creating a listening socket from iOS.

Comment: I feel I should warn you that a direct connection between devices as you're attempting here is very difficult to do robustly. It may work ok when both devices are on the same wifi, but beyond that... you're in for a lot of pain. What type of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: So I totally understand WiFi is just not super stable and you're going to have allot of inconsistencies here, but basically this is just to get a proof of concept working with sockets, that way once I get the wifi thing figured out I route the socket through a USB connection with will be much easier. But basically I'm trying to send about 4 images per second from an Android device to an iOS device. Then I need to send a message back to the Android device and basically loop this over and over again. Its a complex project without a doubt. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Post back here when you're able to get the basics working.